# Why can't I build my app on the build server after adding the "CodeScanner Library" extension?

Tags: codenameone

I am using Netbeans 12 with Maven

Image 1.
a. Create the "Test" application.
b. I clean and build (just to ensure it works - it shows me temporary signature message).
c. I install the extension
d. I solve problems of the project on the common folder.

Image #2.
I clean and build the project.

Image #3
Note that the "BUILD SUCCES" message appears in the console, but the window asking me if I authorize the use of a temporary signature does not appear.

Note: The app runs perfectly in the simulator.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the error log you get from the build server? Typically it would indicate if there's a missing configuration or build hint.